# Store fingerprint data in a database for data collection

Tags: android, database, realm, fingerprint

I am a begginer in android development. I am working with a team on a project for data collection of development of malnourished childrens and child labour. And our app need tracking children through fingerprint so that they can be saved. Can anyone explain me how to store finger print data in any database like Realm or SQLite ?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you done any research on your own? Please show some due-diligence.

Comment: What do you want to store template or image ? What do you want to do with this stored data after  ? identification ?

Comment: @laurentY, something similar issue with me also, I need to store fingerprint in MySql DB, I searched for that, someone says fingerprint can be used only for authentication purpose in android devices, you can't extract and store it in DB!! is there any API to get fingerprint data?

Comment: @LaurentY I want to store the image of fingerprint to the database. How can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store finger print in binary format (`byte[]`). For example you can create [RealmObject](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#models) with field `byte[] fingerprint`:

```
public class MyData extends RealmObject{
     private byte[] fingerprint;

     public void setFingerptint(byte[] fingerprint){this.fingerprint = fingerprint;}
     public byte[] getFingerprint(){return this.fingerprint;}
}
```

Create `MyData` object you can at [transaction block](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#transaction-blocks):

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        MyData data = realm.createObject(MyData.class);
        data.setFingerprint(fingerprintData);
    }
});
```

#### Keep in mind

For [performance reasons](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#general) maximum size of `String` and `byte[]` fields is 16MB